# How to display cookie value in JSF facelet (xhtml file) by using implicit object; "cookie"

Tags: session, jsf, cookies, xhtml, implicit

I wrote a code as follows in JSF facelet(xhtml file)

```
   ${cookie}
```

If I run the xhtml file on a web app server. The below is displayed on the screen.

```
   {JSESSIONID=javax.servlet.http.Cookie@faf91d8}
```

However, it seems to be the address of where the cookie instance is stored.
I want to see the value(sessionid) in the cookie.
I tried this code, but it did not work.

```
   ${cookie[value]}
```

I tried reading the following specifications in JCP, but I could not find the answer.

```
   https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=372
```

Could you please tell me how to properly write a code to display a value in a cookie? I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from what is printed, it looks like a key-value pair and since [the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnaij/index.html) says it maps to a single cookie,

```
#{cookie['JSESSIONID']}
```

is what returns an actual single cookie. But you still need the value of it so

```
#{cookie['JSESSIONID'].value}
```

is most likely what you need

**See also**

- http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.com/p/jsf-implicit-objects.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html

Comment: Hi Kukeltje, I am sorry for the late reply. Thank you very much for your help! The way of writing the code you taught me successfully worked and I was able to check the value of JSESSIONID.